# Want to go from MANILA to UGANDA

Tags: wordplay, no-computers, geography, word-ladder

How do you get from the word MANILA to UGANDA in the shortest time?

You can change up to 3 letters at a time to form a new 6 letter word **which MUST be either a country name or a capital of a country**.

No rearranging of letters.

Please, no programming either.

Comment: Would lateral thinking be appreciated? Would you like to know that it would take over a 16 hr flight to go from Manila to Uganda? https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Kampala,+Uganda/Manila,+NCR,+Philippines/@7.1378883,58.3444547,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x177dbc0f9d74b39b:0x4538903dd96b6fec!2m2!1d32.5825197!2d0.3475964!1m5!1m1!1s0x3397ca03571ec38b:0x69d1d5751069c11f!2m2!1d120.9842195!2d14.5995124

Comment: Change meaning substituion only, or is deletion/addition ok?

Comment: n_palum  In a way I was also thinking shortest distance. So the final solution should involve the shortest distance and hence shortest time too. Going back and forth all over the world could mean very long time. Of course I should have made it clear. But it is a word changing puzzle

Comment: Viktor. Must only substitute up to 3 letters to create a new 6 letter word (Country or Capital). Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My solution is longer than Alconja's, but has a more orthodox spelling ;-)

> Manila -> **P**an**am**a -> **H**a**v**a**n**a -> **Guy**ana -> **L**u**s**a**k**a -> Lu**and**a -> **Ug**anda

Formating courtesy of Jonathan Allen. Apparently my bold face letters made no sense to anyone but me. Story of my life...

Comment: Pfft. Spelling's overrated anyway. :) (+1)

Comment: Not sure I get the placement of the boldface. EDIT: I think I get it, looks like you are shifting letters around, but you don't need to...

Comment: This makes more sense to me: Manila -> **P**an**am**a -> **H**a**v**a**n**a -> **Guy**ana -> **L**u**s**a**k**a -> Lu**and**a -> **Ug**anda (for copy-paste, that is: `**P**an**am**a -> **H**a**v**a**n**a -> **Guy**ana -> **L**u**s**a**k**a -> Lu**and**a -> **Ug**anda`)

Comment: Okay, I changed it. But for the record, I was bolding the...er...letters that stayed the same in the next word? Maybe?

Comment: Dr Xorile. Good answer. One thing I was thinking of (Lateral) was the shortest time comment in my puzzle. Geographically which solution will take shortest time (equated to distance which is not always true) ? But I do appreciate that it is lot more work like homework. My answer involves Tarawa and Tirana, not optimum obviously

Comment: That's an interesting variant, @DeepakMahulikar. Working out travel time would not be too tricky, though a bit of homework if you wanted to find legit travel routes. Distance should be possible to do algorithmically.

Answer (score 8):

Dr Xorile's answer does seem to be the shortest at seven entries, but there are 5 possible variations, for a total of 6 solutions:

> Manila > Canada > Havana > Guyana > Guinea > Luanda > Uganda
> Manila > Canada > Havana > Guyana > Lusaka > Luanda > Uganda
> Manila > Panama > Havana > Guyana > Guinea > Luanda > Uganda
> Manila > Panama > Havana > Guyana > Lusaka > Luanda > Uganda
> Manila > Manama > Havana > Guyana > Guinea > Luanda > Uganda
> Manila > Manama > Havana > Guyana > Lusaka > Luanda > Uganda

Answer (score 7):

If you like taking the scenic route, I found a path with 17 places:

> Manila -> Canada -> Havana -> Panama -> Manama -> Monaco -> Malabo -> Malawi -> Tarawa -> Ottawa -> Astana -> Tirana -> Guyana -> Guinea -> Luanda -> Rwanda -> Uganda

Although I must confess, some programming was involved.

I used wikipedia's [List of national capitals in alphabetical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals_in_alphabetical_order) for the source of capitals and countries.

There's an 18 place path if you count Sana'a:

> Manila -> Canada -> Havana -> Panama -> Sana'a -> Manama -> Monaco -> Malabo -> Malawi -> Tarawa -> Ottawa -> Astana -> Tirana -> Guyana -> Guinea -> Luanda -> Rwanda -> Uganda

---

Other interesting paths:

Longest shortest routes between two places:

> 11 'Bissau -> Nassau -> Maseru -> Majuro -> Malabo -> Manama -> Havana -> Guyana -> Guinea -> Luanda -> Rwanda'
>  11 'Bissau -> Nassau -> Maseru -> Majuro -> Malabo -> Manama -> Havana -> Guyana -> Guinea -> Luanda -> Uganda'
>  11 'Rwanda -> Luanda -> Guinea -> Guyana -> Havana -> Manama -> Malabo -> Majuro -> Maseru -> Nassau -> Warsaw'
>  11 'Uganda -> Luanda -> Guinea -> Guyana -> Havana -> Manama -> Malabo -> Majuro -> Maseru -> Nassau -> Warsaw'

Longest scenic routes between two places:

> 25 Russia -> Lusaka -> Luanda -> Guinea -> Guyana -> Tirana -> Astana -> Ottawa -> Tarawa -> Harare -> Havana -> Canada -> Manila -> Panama -> Sana'a -> Manama -> Malawi -> Malabo -> Maputo -> Majuro -> Maseru -> Roseau -> Bissau -> Nassau -> Warsaw
>  25 Rwanda -> Uganda -> Luanda -> Guinea -> Guyana -> Tirana -> Astana -> Ottawa -> Tarawa -> Harare -> Havana -> Canada -> Manila -> Panama -> Sana'a -> Manama -> Malawi -> Malabo -> Maputo -> Majuro -> Maseru -> Roseau -> Bissau -> Nassau -> Warsaw
>  25 Uganda -> Rwanda -> Luanda -> Guinea -> Guyana -> Tirana -> Astana -> Ottawa -> Tarawa -> Harare -> Havana -> Canada -> Manila -> Panama -> Sana'a -> Manama -> Malawi -> Malabo -> Maputo -> Majuro -> Maseru -> Roseau -> Bissau -> Nassau -> Warsaw

Comment: and what about Sana'a ?

Comment: @JanIvan my perl regex counted it as a match, but I manually pulled it out.

Comment: Martin  you can jump directly from Manila to Panama to Tarawa. They are all scenic

Comment: Can you find the two destinations that are the furthest distance apart. I guess the end points of the diameter in graph theory terms. Ie the two points so that the minimum distance between them is a maximum

Comment: Astana has changed name to Nur-Sultan